# Spring Boot and JasperReportsViewResolver

Tags: spring, jasper-reports, spring-boot

I´m using the `JasperReportsViewResolver` class to provide support for the reports of my app,my code looks like this:

```
@Bean
public JasperReportsViewResolver getJasperReportsViewResolver() {
  JasperReportsViewResolver resolver = new JasperReportsViewResolver();

  resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/reports/");
  resolver.setSuffix(".jasper");
  resolver.setJdbcDataSource(dataSource);
  resolver.setViewNames("report*");
  resolver.setViewClass(JasperReportsMultiFormatView.class);
  resolver.setOrder(0);
  return resolver;
}
```

My problem is, if my Tomcat directory installation contains white spaces,I receive a weird `JRException` as listed below:

```
Thu Apr 09 08:33:57 GMT-03:00 2015
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Request processing failed; nested exception is net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Resource not found at : /C:/development/Apache/apache%20tomcat-8.0.20/webapps/reports/WEB-INF/classes/report/reportPath/myReport.jasper
```

Any ideas?Trimming the directory name is not a option.

Comment: Do you need the preceeding "/" in the prefix? I've usually seen it as "classpath:path/to/my/package"